# In jmeter how to update parameter value on each iteration of the loop, but using single user only

Tags: jmeter

In jmeter how to update parameter value on each iteration of the loop, but using single user only.

scenario is i login into the application with single user and perform multiple iteration of same task with different parameters.

i have used loop controller also, but the issue is that it uses only the first value in the parameter list nad perform the given iteration with the same input.

also, application does not support multiple login from single machine.

Comment: In general, in order to update request before sending you can use BSF PreProcessor for your sampler in conjunction with user defined variable defined. But it is not pretty clear what parameters you want to change and how you read list of parameters

Answer (score 1):

This is solved by using a **User Parameters Pre-processor**. This guarantees that the params are fetched/regenerated anew everytime an iteration starts.

For random variables for example use `${__Random(1,1000000000)}`

Comment: Thank you for this answer! It helped me figure out why I had a function `${__RandomString(10, 0123456789) }` placed in User Parameters at thread group level, regenerating a new string between two requests of the same thread group, even though they're part of the same iteration. I had to put a User Parameters PreProcessor instead. Then two requests in same iteration use the same string.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need to send just something new each time - JMeter provides a number of functions like __Random() __RandomString() or __counter()
2. If you have data, you want to pass as the parameter somewhere in CSV file - you'll need [CSV Data Set Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) Element added as a child of your request.
3. If your data lives in database - you'll need to insert [JDBC Sampler](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65143-using-jdbc-sampler-in-jmeter-2-6) somewhere, execute query and store result in JMeter variable.
4. None of above? JMeter can be scripted via [Beanshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675711/how-to-use-bean-shell-sampler-in-jmeter) which allows execution of arbitrary Java code and provides access to JMeter components APIs